# Grails Table using DataTables

Tags: java, postgresql, grails, datatable

I would like to ask for guidance here, I am dealing with millions of data on the Database (PostgreSQL), to show the user logs that are created in our system. I used DataTable for pagination and search purposes, but when I access that page it does not load, is there any way to speed the loading of  DataTable?

### This is my HTML code.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User</th>
                            <th>Date/Time</th>
                            <th>Activity</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>IP Adress</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <g:each in="${auditLogInstanceList}" status="i" var="auditLogInstance">
                            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                                <td>${fieldValue(bean: auditLogInstance, field: "userMaster.name")}</td>
                                <td>${auditLogInstance.date}</td>
                                <td>${auditLogInstance.auditType.description}</td>
                                <td>${auditLogInstance.description}</td>
                                <td>${fieldValue(bean: auditLogInstance, field: "ipAddress")}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "deferRender": true
                    } );
                    } );
                </script>
            </div>
```

### This is the Controller.

```html
def index(Integer max) {
        if(params.offset==null){
            params.offset=0
        }
        if (params.query == null) {
            def AuditLogList = AuditLog.createCriteria().list (params) {
                or {
                    eq("auditType", AuditType.get(1))
                    eq("auditType", AuditType.get(2))
                    eq("auditType", AuditType.get(16))
                }
                order("date", "desc")
            }
            respond AuditLogList, model:[params:params,AuditLogInstanceCount: AuditLogList.totalCount]
        }
        else{
            def AuditLogList = AuditLog.createCriteria().list (params) {
                and {
                    ilike("description", "%${params.query}%")
                }            
            }
            respond AuditLogList, model:[params:params,AuditLogInstanceCount: AuditLogList.totalCount]
        }
        return
    }
```

Comment: If you have millions of records sorting or using like may be too expensive for the db engine to be performed. You should probably log the query to be perfomed, run some kind of `EXPLAIN` to get an execution plan and check what's going to be executed and it cost.

Comment: yeah i figured, but i just wanted to see how will the Datatable plugin can handle such loads of data.

Comment: You can use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) as one way to handle (potentially) millions of records in DataTables. This approach delegates all paging/sorting/filtering logic to the server - and the server only ever passes one page of results to DataTables - so, maybe 10 records instead of 10,000 or a million. Otherwise, the processing work performed by DataTables and your browser will almost certainly be prohibitively slow.

Comment: Other options (which may or may not work in your case) are: [deferred rendering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender), and [infinite scrolling](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/).

Comment: the server-side that you mentioned, i need to change my grails code on that? because i saw examples on the page you've given me using ajax, and the data there are just static, how about when it ill be fetching data from the database?